# Memory dump size does not match size of MTD partition

Tags: microcontroller, serial, embedded, non-volatile-memory, nand-flash

Device with Linux embedded system on NAND flash memory. I did memory dump of some MTD devices partitions use serial console, from U-boot bootloader use available commands.
First I read MTD partition to address in the memory, then dumped memory from that address to the terminal window. 
For example, MTD partition   `0x01d60000-0x01e60000 : "FPAR"` MTD partition size is `0x00100000 = 1048576 bytes`

```
nand read 0x20000000 0x01d60000 0x00100000
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x1d60000, size 0x100000
1048576 bytes read: OK
md.b 0x20000000 0x00100000
```

Then saved log file with dump as text file, cut out extra stuff before and after the dump and coverted it to binary use

```
xxd -r -p dump.txt dump.bin
```

Resulting bin file size 1,310,860 bytes is mismatching MTD partion size (1,048,576 bytes), its much larger. Is the problem related to hex data conversion or the dump process have errors? I understand that MTD partion size of 1048576 bytes is size assigned to the whole MTD partition, the actual data on partition takes much smaller space, the large space filled with hex 'ff' values. Additionally, can anyone advice good utility for hex to bin data conversion?

**Edit:** I tried the same steps with 64 bytes data size, and used Raw log session mode, after trimming extra stuff, the resulting ascii file is 318 bytes. After dump conversion, the bin size is 87 bytes.

```
20000000: a0 7c 4f fa 62 61 75 64 72 61 74 65 3d 31 31 35    .|O.baudrate=115
20000010: 32 30 30 00 65 74 68 61 64 64 72 3d 46 46 3a 46    200.ethaddr=FF:F
20000020: 46 3a 46 46 3a 46 46 3a 46 46 3a 46 46 00 6e 65    F:FF:FF:FF:FF.ne
20000030: 74 6d 61 73 6b 3d 32 35 35 2e 32 35 35 2e 32 35    tmask=255.255.25
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve by doing this? What do you plan to do with this file?

Comment: Try the same procedure on a much smaller amount of memory (eg. 64 bytes) then examine the results at each stage to see where the 25% extra bytes are being added.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I tried the same with 64 bytes size data, edited dump with gedit: resulting ascii file size= 318 bytes. So `gedit` corrupts the file. But even if I edit file with another editor, for example Geany, the resulting file size is same.

Comment: Why do you insist on doing this blindly?   Use a tool like `hexdump` to actually *look* at the files and *see* what is different.

Comment: Ok, I should convert only hex values from hexdump, without the ASCII representation table.

Comment: Seems I used incorrect way to convert hex dump to bin file, only hex values should be converted, the ASCII table need be cleaned out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `xxd -r -seek -0x20000000 dump.txt dump.bin`

`xxd -r -p` expects input in plain hexadecimal format, without addresses or ASCII. `xxd -r` without `-seek` assumes that addresses are zero-based, and will seek or zero-pad its output to skip over regions not present in the dump (the first 0x20000000 = 536870912 bytes).

Comment: Yes, this command does the correct conversion, binary output matches the actual size of MTD partition. Thank you.